# Найти подстроку Kotlin

Tags: строки, kotlin

Кажется вопрос очень простой, но почему-то не работает
вот код

```
for (i in symbols)
{
 Log.i(TAG,"${i} ${user.first_name} ${user.second_name} ${i.contains(user.first_name, true)} ${ i.contains(user.second_name, true)}")
    if (i.contains(user.first_name, true) || i.contains(user.second_name, true))
     {
       Log.i(TAG,"Have")
        included = true
        break
     }

}
```

Вот лог

```
B Boroow Elderly false false
B Igor Banov false false
```

Comment: может не `i.contains(user.first_name, true)` а `user.first_name.contains(i, true)`?

Comment: А это что-то изменит?

Comment: у вас проверка, есть ли **в** букве "B" слово "Boroow", а надо наоборот

Comment: Пасиба, что-то я совсем заработался)